# Why does this not render?

Tags: rendering

Using Cycles Render, why does this not render the scene as seen through the camera?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3504807/candyHeartReTopo_01.blend

Comment: Please make the text of the question more specific. All of your question revolves around folks downloading a file. Moreover you are using a non permanent link to your file, so that if the file disappears your question will make no sense at all. Please take the time to describe what you have done and show images of your settings, sometimes it is a lot easier to help without having to spend time downloading and poking through your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the plane that uses the particle system, go to it's modifiers and hit convert at the particle system modifier.

For the other big heart in the sky, select it, go to object settings and set the duplication to 'none'. Everything will be rendered.